# what command in gdb is same as pathmap in dbx?

Tags: c++, linux, c++11

When I use gdb on a coredump it reports some .so it cannot find in a certain path.  For example:

> Symbol file not found for /root/a/xx.so

I do not have administrator rights to create a directory in root, but I do have the xx.so, and in dbx, I can use pathmap to change the path where I can continue the debug. But in gdb I cannot find the same command.

In addition, I do not have the rights to change the compiler command. That is to say, I can't change the linker path to re-compile.

Comment: Is it possible to run gdb on the machine that created the core?

Comment: No,it was from a living site,and can't be reporduced in lab.

Comment: Ok but you say you have a core file which was generated by the machine - is it not easy to install gdb there and examine it - since gdb will have very little overhead on a production machine.

Comment: The problem manchine is in customer's hand,I ftp the corefile to my lab manchine,but I do not have right to operate customer's manchine or I am against the company's security principle....

Comment: Makes total sense - the joys of operation support - cannot you put the libraries on the same place on your own lab machine?

Comment: It will cause a lot of time to re-build the right environment,so that is why I want to know if gdb have "pathmap"....

Comment: I am sure it does since it is newer than dbx but it I am too lazy to read the docs to see if it does

Comment: http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Separate-Debug-Files.html ?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want `set solib-search-path`, which takes a colon-delimited list of directory names to search for shared libraries when searching in `sysroot` fails.

A related command, `set sysroot` (a.k.a `set solib-absolute-prefix`), allows you to set any directory as the root used for loading libraries with absolute path names, but you would need to insure that the libraries are laid out in the proper directory structure under the new root, and it sounds like you don't want to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `dir` command to change to the location of the file.

Answer (score 1):

The command you are looking for is

```
set substitute-path <from> <to>
```